# How to store result of quartz job in session?

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler, grails-2.0

I have installed Quartz plugin in my Grails 2.1 application. Every 5 minutes one job is triggered that will calculate some numbers. The numbers are being shown on the side bar of every page. The calculated results will change frequently and my goal is when users refresh their screen they can see the new result on their sidebar. 
Right now my approach is to send ajax call to a controller and grab the result from the database and render it on the screen.

Is there any way to store (cache) the calculated result from the JOB somewhere other than database so that my views can use them without executing query each time users click on a link or refresh the screen?

I thought about session but not sure its even possible outside of normal web request or its a good solution at all. Is there any solution or alternative approach?
Thanks

```
class MonitoringJob {
    def calculatorService
    def name  = 'Monitoring'
    def group = 'ApplicationGroup'
    static triggers = {
        simple name: 'mySimpleTrigger', startDelay: 60000, repeatInterval: 30000
    }

    def execute() {
        def results = calculatorService.runCalculators()
            //something like this:   session.results  =result
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Services in Grails are by default singletons, so the `calculatorService` accessed in the Quartz job will be the same `calculatorService` accessed in other classes in which it is wired (e.g., controllers).

Just store the values at the class level within your `calculatorService` and add an accessor method for the controllers to retrieve the data.

```
class CalculatorService {

    ConcurrentHashMap cache = [:]

    def runCalculators() {
        // Do calculations
        cache.result1 = calculatedResult1
        // etc...
    }

    def retrieveCalculation(String key) {
        cache[(key)]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grailsApplication`.  Just inject `grailsApplication` into your job, then save the value with an assignment `grailsApplication.config.calcResults = calculatorService.runCalculators`

You may want to initialize the `grailsApplication.config.calcResults` value in `Bootstrap.groovy` as well so it's available before the job runs for the first time.

Comment: Does whoever downvoted this answer care to explain their objection?