# Application wide map

Tags: grails

I want a quartz job to populate a map (from a web services call) on regular intervals and then access that map from the web layer (to display to the user).

I was thinking just doing a service (given that a service is singleton), but am a bit worried about [the recommendation not to store state in a service](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/guide/services.html#scopedServices).

```
class MapService {
    def map = [:]
}
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: i would store the map into the db, and on every intervall fetch the map from db and push new entrys and save, so on the weblayer you only fetch from the db. Another idea would be that you do no intervalled population of the map but always when a user requests to display them, then its persistent

Comment: i was hoping not to save them to the db... or fetch them when the user visits the page :)

Comment: Have you been able to achieve what you were looking for?

Comment: @Alidad Yep, using your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not worrying about keeping data in memory while the app is running, you can use `ConcurrentHashMap` in your service and store the data you need. Look at it as a cache not reliable storage though.

As you also said, services are singleton `only one instance of the service ever exists` and `concurrentMap` is `A hash table supporting full concurrency of retrievals and adjustable expected concurrency for updates.`

Ex:

```
calss MyService() {

    ConcurrentHashMap cacheMap = [:]

    def retrieveCache(String key) {
        cacheMap[(key)]
    }

    def resetCache(){
        cacheMap = [:]
    }

    def doSomething(){
        ..
        cacheMap.put(key,value)
    }

}
```

similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319037/how-to-store-result-of-quartz-job-in-session)